# Nginx keeps resolving wrong site with https

Tags: http, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I have several sites for nginx placed in 
/etc/nginx/sites-available

recently I've added https with letsencrypt for one of the sites (let's say test1.com).

All other sites don't have https configured.

Now if I when I make https request for any other site  (let's say test2.com).

https://test2.com

I got chrome "waring Your connection is not private"

And nginx tries to open https://test1.com site.

Http requests works ok.

Here is my default conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 433 default_server;
    listen [::]:433 default_server;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;i
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

here is mine test1 site conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name test1.com;

        location / {
                return 301 https://www.test1.com$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.test1.com;

        location / {
                return 301 https://www.test1.com$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.test1.com;   
        ssl on;

        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+AES;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       ssl_stapling on;
       ssl_stapling_verify on;

       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload";
       add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
       add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test1.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test1.com/privkey.pem;


       root /var/www/test1;

       index index.php index.html index.htm;


       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
      }


       location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

       }
       location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
       }

 }
```

Here is mine test2.com conf file

```
# I've tried this - didn't help
#server {
#    listen      433 ssl;
#    server_name www.test2.com;
#    return      444;
#}
server {
       listen   80;
       root /var/www/test2;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       server_name www.test2.com;
       server_name test2.com;

       location / {
                    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;i
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       }

       location ~ /\.ht {
                                    deny all;
       }

}
```

**I'm not trying to use test1.com's cert for test2.com it I'm trying to prevent test2.com working over https.**
If I create an ssl for test2.com it will work, but I don't want it.
I want test2.com work without http and have some kind of reject for https requests.

Answer (score 0):

The way HTTPS works is to verify the certificate for xyz.com so that the browser knows that the site and it's cert matches.

You need to get another cert for test2.com in your case

If you use the test1.com cert on test2.com, the browser informs you that the certs are not matching (i.e. the website is not test1.com)

**Update**

Try putting the below block in conf to prevent undefined server names. If its an auto-route problem, this will be fixed

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}
```

**Update 2**

Remove the following lines from your default.conf

```
listen 433 default_server;
listen [::]:433 default_server;
```

Comment: I know, if I create SSL cert for test2.com it works correctly, but I don't want to. 
I have a lot of domains and most of them don't need https connection can I somehow reject https requests for them?

Comment: > The way HTTPS works is to verify the certificate for xyz.com so that the browser knows that the site and it's cert matches.

I'm not trying to use test1.com's  cert for  test2.com  it I'm trying  prevent test2.com working over https

Comment: Sorry .. my bad. Please use some formatting as your problem statement got lost in your summary. And your question too doesn't do much in the way of explaining the issue

Comment: Looks much better :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I've tried it.
But in when I do nginx -t I got

nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

And of course, nothing changes after nginx restart.

I've put all your strings default.conf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent test2.com for use of SSL cert then you have to redirect all ::443 request to ::80 in test2.com conf instead of "return 444";

```
server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name test2.com;

        location / {
                return 301 http://www.test2.com$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name www.test2.com;

        location / {
                return 301 http://www.test1.com$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
       listen   80;
       root /var/www/test2;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       server_name www.test2.com;
       server_name test2.com;

       location / {
                    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;i
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       }

       location ~ /\.ht {
                                    deny all;
       }

}
```